# Makefile dir function doesn't expand as expected in for loop

Tags: makefile

I want to iterate through a list of files, execute `cd` in their respective directories before executing a command.

So I would like to use `$(dir $(FILES))` function to get the directory, but it seems not to work properly in the `for` loop.

```
FILES=../dir1/file1 ../dir2/file2

.PHONY: all

all:
    @for f in $(FILES); do \
        echo $$f in $(dir $${f}) ; \
    done
```

outputs

```
../dir1/file1 in ./
../dir2/file2 in ./
```

The `$(dir $${f})` gets expanded to `./` instead of `../dirN`.

Note :

- Writing only `echo $(dir $(FILES))` outside of the `for` loop outputs `../dir1/ ../dir2/` as expected.
- using `$(abspath ...)` doesn't work either.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing make constructs (`dir`) and shell constructs. Unfortunately they are not evaluated at the same time. Make evaluates its constructs **before** passing the recipe to the shell, once for all, not during the execution of the recipe by the shell. When expanding your recipe (before passing it to the shell) it transforms it into:

```
for f in ../dir1/file1 ../dir2/file2; do echo $f in ./; done
```

because when make expands `$(dir $${f})` it first expands the parameter:

```
$(dir ${f})
```

and then, as there is no `/` in the string `${f}`, the expansion of the `dir` function replaces it with `./`. From the GNU make manual:

> ```
> $(dir names…)
> ```
>
> Extracts the directory-part of each file name in names. The directory-part of the file name is everything up through (and
>   including) the last slash in it. If the file name contains no slash,
>   the directory part is the string `./`. For example,
>
> ```
> $(dir src/foo.c hacks)
> ```
>
> produces the result `src/ ./`.

Anyway, mixing make and shell constructs is usually not what you want to do (there are exceptions). You could use only shell constructs:

```
all:
    @for f in $(FILES); do \
        echo $$f in $$(dirname $$f) ; \
    done
```

Or you could use a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) to get completely rid of the shell loop and let make iterate over a list of similar targets:

```
FILES = ../dir1/file1 ../dir2/file2
FOOS  = $(addsuffix .foo,$(FILES))

.PHONY: all $(FOOS)

all: $(FOOS)

$(FOOS): %.foo:
    @echo $* in $(dir $*)
```

Comment: Right, I was confused because I thought `$$f` would be expanded to `../dirN/fileN` before executing `$(dir $$f)`, and it *would* contain `/`. Aparently not. Thanks!